# touch events in attachments iphone not working

Tags: html, ios, iphone

JS touch events in an .html file that I mail as an attachment to an iPhone5 (OS9.2), are never executed because a touch on the screen is intercepted by the Mail and interpreted as DONE.  I'm new to this. Am I missing something obvious? The following code works in XCodeSimulator but not in a real phone. Is there a workaround? Are .html files unsupported in an attachment, for some reason?

Below is a typical test code I'm  using. I prefer to work in vanilla JS, rather than JQuery, but I'd be grateful for any suggestions or advice, whatever.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
    <style>
 #mycanvas{
  position: absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
  border:4px solid;
 }
 </style>
   <script>
function init() {
 var touchzone = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
 touchzone.addEventListener("touchstart",draw,false);
 }
function draw() {
 var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
if(canvas.getContext) {
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 ctx.fillRect(event.touches[0].pageX-100, event.touches[0].pageY-100,10,10);
  }
 }
  </script>
   </head>
 <body onload="init()">
   <canvas id="mycanvas" width="500" height="500">
   Canvas element not supported.
   </canvas>
<h2> Tap inside rectangle to leave a spot. Outside leaves nothing.</h2>
 </body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

We realized that an .html e-mail attachment cannot work in iOS. Placing the file in Public folder on Dropbox gives it a web address that the phone can link. This works for us so far.